# SearchController changes the size of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchcontroller

The size of my tableView mysteriously changes heights when the search controller is active like the images I attached below.

The image in the far left is the initial state. Middle image is when the search controller is active and the last image is when the search controller is dismissed.

[image]

I tried setting the content size of the tableview when the search controller is active, in the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` without any luck.

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

P.S. The items you see are just dummy posts.

Comment: What is your current code? That may help solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set **edgesForExtendedLayout** property to be under Top Bar using code 
or storyboard

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you! I will post my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the extendedLayOut to 0

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.init(rawValue: 0)
```

However, the status bar was covering the search bar so I hide the status bar when the searchController is active

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
return searchController.isActive

}
```